# Eq(0) versus :first-child

Tags: php, jquery, html

I found many answers that it has no differences between :first-child and eq(0).
But when i do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  $("ul.tab-nav li").eq(0).addClass("active");});

 </script>
  <?php
     // select 2 element.
   for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)   
     {
  ?>
          <ul class="tab-nav">
<?php 
       for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)      
      {
?>
               <li>  write st here </li>
<?php
      }
?>
          </ul>
<?php 
   }
?>
```

The result is:

```
<ul class= "tab-nav">
    <li class= "active">write st here</li>
    <li>write st here</li>
</ul>
<ul class= "tab-nav">
    <li>write st here</li>
    <li>write st here</li>
</ul>
```

When i change the script

```
 $(ul.tab-nav li ).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

to

```
$(ul.tab-nav li:first-child ).addClass("active");
```

The result is:

```
 <ul class= "tab-nav">
        <li class= "active">write st here</li>
        <li>write st here</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class= "tab-nav">
        <li class= "active">write st here</li>
        <li>write st here</li>
    </ul>
```

Am I wrong? What is a right answer? it is equivalent or different?

Comment: :eq(0) is equivalent to :first , but as you see, it's not always equivalent to :first-child.

Answer (score 1):

`.eq(0)` is finding the first element that matches that value; `:first-child` is finding the first child element of each `ul.tab-nav`.

---

**Breaking it down**

```
$(ul.tab-nav li ).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

- `$(ul.tab-nav li)` finds all the list items under each `ul.tab-nav`, of which there are four.
- `.eq(0)` only selects the first of those four elements.
- `.addClass("active")` adds the class "active" to that selected element.

---

```
$(ul.tab-nav li:first-child ).addClass("active");
```

- `$(ul.tab-nav li:first child)` finds the first `li` element under each `ul.tab-nav`, of which there are two.
- `.addClass("active")` adds the class "active" to both those elements.

Comment: Thanks. I have once more question: why when i changed <li> to <div> it didn't take a effect any more? It didn't add the "active" class.

Comment: Because you're looking for the first `li` element in each case, not `div`. Change `li` and `li:first-child` to `div` and `div:first-child`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(ul.tab-nav li ).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

Will get a list of all li's that are children of ul.tab-nav, and select only the first one (of them all). This executes once, regardless of how many ul's there are.

```
$(ul.tab-nav li:first-child ).addClass("active");
```

Will get every li that is the first child of its parent, this will execute once for each ul.

Comment: Thanks. I have once more question: 
why when i changed <li> to <div> it didn't take a effect any more?
It didn't add the "active" class.